# Object doesn't support this property or method in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am having this error on Ie8 only. the line specified by the debugger is

```
finally{b=[e,f],c=0}}
```

**Object doesn't support this property or method ----- jquery.min.js?ver=latest, line 2 character 15738**

P.S: Please don't mark it as duplicate, i have thorough research and i really need help on this.

Comment: Can you give some information as to what you're trying to do when this occurs?

Comment: That's very vague - have you tried using the non-minified version of jQuery to get more detail?

Comment: i m using wordpress and a plugin (Rate This Page). The rating plugin works fine with all the browsers but its not working on IE8.

Comment: You need to find the line in YOUR code not in the jQuery code which causes the error.

Comment: Could you give the address of the jquery file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that both b and c have *already* been declared properly:

```
var b, c;
```

If you've not done this it is almost certainly the reason that you're seeing the error. IE8 looks for an existing variable in scope (one that was defined using the 'var' keyword) and if it can't find one you'll see this message.

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is to upgrade to IE9 and ask your users to update their browser.. and if they are on IE8 or lower, than they just simply dont deserve to view your site :)

Comment: I am going to hang this answer on the wall in the office :)))))
How do you believe one would ASK their users to upgrade? If a significant amount of users with IE8 WILL use your website you are obliged to make it work on IE8 and there still ARE websites with a lot people from IE8 coming. There are some cases you just have to make it working.